# Best practice to create entry (relationship)?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to figure out what is best practice to create new row.

Let say we have this in the controller:

```
$this->noteRepository->addNote($request->user(), $name, $note);
```

Two working solution of `addNote` method in the `noteRepository` class, for example:

Option 1 - This will create entry using `noteModel`

```
public function addNote($user, $name, $note)
{
     return $this->noteModel->create([
         'user_id' => $user->id,
         'name'    => $name,
         'note'   => $note,
     ]);
}
```

Option 2 - there is a `notes()` method in the user model.

```
public function addNote($user, $name, $note)
{
     return $user->notes()->create([
         'user_id' => $user->id,
         'name'    => $name,
         'note'   => $note,
     ]);
}
```

In the `user` model look like this:

```
public function notes()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Note::class);
}
```

Which is recommended approach to use and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 2 looks better with some modification as:

```
public function addNote($user, $name, $note)
{
     return $user->notes()->create([
         'name'    => $name,
         'note'   => $note,
     ]);
}
```

It's because you don't have to manually set the FK and it's more elegant and readable. This way you will be utilizing Laravel at the fullest.

**Advantages**

- The relationship will be set automatically.
- The name of the foreign key column doesn't matter (it only needs to be defined in the relationship declaration).

Comment: Agree. I'm using this approach as well.

Comment: iCode  if addNote is a method in the user model can i use $this->notes()->create(); and remove $user from the params?

Comment: @borracciaBlu Yes, you can do this.